# Why does saying "Swiper, no swiping!" three times prevent Swiper from swiping?

Tags: dora-the-explorer

In Dora the Explorer, Swiper often tries to swipe an object that Dora and Boots need to reach their destination. If they confront him and say "Swiper, no swiping!" three times before he reaches it, he'll say "Oh, man!" and leave. However, I've seen in some episodes they only manage to say it once and he grabs the item.

Is there any in-universe explanation for why they need to say this three times, or for how it prevents him from then taking the item? Clearly, simply being seen doing it is not sufficient to prevent him.

I've only seen most of seasons 1 and 3 of Dora the Explorer. I have not seen the full seven seasons or any other related canon material for Dora the Explorer, so I'm wondering if the answer appears there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Dora the Explorer.  Questions regarding children's programs where the fantasy elements primarily consist of anthropomorphic talking animals have been deemed off topic in the past.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Please take tangential discussion on on-topicness to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18203/discussion-on-question-by-sterno-why-does-saying-swiper-no-swiping-three-tim) or Meta.  Keep the comments related to improving this post.

Comment: You are kidding, right?

Comment: I found an example of [the meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5117/23159) that TGnat mentioned.

Comment: @numaroth Dora goes beyond simply having talking animals (there are trolls with their own realm under the bridge, a magical forest where Unicornio is king, etc), so I think the question it links, [Are children's literature and cartoon's for children on-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic), seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Sterno - "Would a serious fan of the science fiction or fantasy genres consider spending any amount of effort digging into the details of a children's cartoon?". Yes, I would.

Comment: @Sterno Fair enough, I decided to link to the more recent question since, without knowledge of Dora, it seemed relevant and it contained a link to the [children's cartoon question.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/683/23159)

Comment: After reading that meta, I think it could use a clearer answer, as I'm not sure if any of the current answers justify this question being closed.

Comment: Closers, no closing!

Comment: My deleted comment said that the work the question is about should have enough development for it to be considered on topic. I don't think Dora has such (it has trolls and unicorns, but only as the setting seems fit, not as part of a more complex environment)

Comment: Seems like a candidate for migration to Movies & TV.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Needs to be 3 times

Comment: @deworde No, around here the magic number to chant is 5.

Comment: probably works in the same way as Beetlejuice Beetlejuice Beetlejuice

Comment: Defending the existence of SciFi/Fantasy elements in the series: the show technically takes place inside of a computer game (as evidenced by the frequently-appearing mouse cursor), which makes Dora, Boots, Swiper, etc. artificial life and potentially AI.

Comment: @deworde **Closers, no closing**

Comment: @DogeTheExplorer All hail King Unicornio!

Comment: I love the fact that this is actually a question that people are interested in hahaha, i mean i searched it too but why?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is discussed at some considerable length in [this article](http://lifestyle.howstuffworks.com/family/activities/movie-fun-night/how-dora-the-explorer-works4.htm) from howstuffworks. In short, his swiping is to be viewed less as a character *flaw* and more of a character *trait*:

Show co-creator Valerie Walsh gives us some further insight:

> Swiper is a one-dimensional character. **You don’t know why he steals,
>   and we did that on purpose.** Kids this age are learning about more
>   complex thinking. The emotional and psychological reasons behind
>   someone being bad have to be explained so thoroughly that we didn’t
>   want the back-story…. We’ve had this discussion with advisors who
>   wanted us to get into the motivation behind Swiper’s bad behavior. **We
>   decided that it’s cleaner without it. Similar to villains in fairy
>   tales, we don’t get into the why.**

By extension, his motivation for not swiping after being confronted by Dora ("no swiping!") is also **intentionally unexplained**.

---

Out of universe, the show's other co-creator Chris Gifford has [described the phrase](http://lifestyle.howstuffworks.com/family/activities/movie-fun-night/how-dora-the-explorer-works4.htm) as a simple strategy to empower children in dealing with the threat posed by Swiper:

> **And what about Swiper, the villain?**
>
> That was pretty controversial actually at the time. There were a lot
>   of people who asked us not to put Swiper into the show. As a matter of
>   fact, because they kept going through how to reduce or adjust Swiper’s
>   teeth, “Round them out!”
>
> **And I just wanted him to have sharp teeth because the more threatening
>   Swiper was; the more powerful kids felt and be able to stop him. So
>   now they have the strategy to keep saying, “Swiper no swiping”, and
>   then Swiper stops.** And that I think, is a big part of the Dora success
>   because you know he is a threat.

Comment: So, quite literally, the answer is because that's just how he works.

Comment: @Koviko - When the writer says "we deliberately left it vague", all you've got is unfounded speculation! To counter that, I've offered an out-of-universe explanation as well.

Comment: "**unintentionally explained**" or "**intentionally unexplained**"?

Comment: "Unintentionally explained" or "intentionally unexplained"?

Comment: @Dleh Wow, that's weird. If I hadn't taken the time to capitalize the U, I might have beaten you.

Comment: @RyanM haha yeah, if I hadn't taken the time to bold it, I would've been even faster ^_^

Comment: @DLeh - Sigh. Everyone's a critic. Don't forget that you can edit answers...

Comment: @Richard You have way too much rep. We are not worthy to touch it.

Comment: @Richard I didn't want to because I wasn't entirely sure of your intentions. And it would have changed the answer significantly, so I didn't feel qualified to do it. Great answer though!

Comment: @Koviko - Note that I've never rolled back an edit.

Comment: @Richard I'd imagine you can take criticism, by now. I was just being tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @RyanM it takes you ten extra seconds to capitalize a letter? ;-) (he posted 9 seconds before you)

Comment: @TimS. One second to capitalize, 9 seconds for the internal debate whether or not to go back & capitalize it after I pasted it. (Really I just thought it was interesting that our comments were identical apart from that capital letter.)

Comment: I'm so old, I remember when HowStuffWorks was an interesting site containing useful knowledge.

Comment: "No means no!" -

Answer (score 11):

The [unofficial wiki](http://dora.wikia.com/wiki/Swiper) states:

> It is revealed that Swiper started to steal when he saw another fox stealing a little train from a child. After that Swiper took away a witch's shoes and she punished him with a magical curse and told him "You can now be stopped by anyone who says "Swiper no swiping!" three times".

Unfortunately, the reference is uncited, and I don't believe it comes from an actual episode.  In the very first episode, Dora already knows how to stop Swiper.  Nor is it explained in flashback episodes like "Dora's First Trip" or Swiper-centric episodes like "Swiper's Big Adventure."

Swiper's [IMDB biography](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0161528/bio) also gives an uncited reference to a witch's curse.

Comment: The only reference I can find to this seems to be a fanfic;  http://justliz143.weebly.com/new-character-perspective.html

Comment: What a world we live in where Swiper the Fox has his own IMDB biography.

Comment: @Zibbobz We live in a world where a character with millions of fans and millions of dollars in merchandising are spent on him a year. Who meeting that criteria WOULDN'T have an IMDB biopic?

Answer (score 6):

Empirical studies seems to indicate that at least the younger kids need the three times to catch the trigger and have time to say it at least once. I guess they feel better knowing they helped stopping Swiper ;-)

Comment: Whilst this is a good out of universe answer, the question asks for an in-universe answer.