# What happened to Boots, Tico and the rest?

Tags: dora-the-explorer

I was watching *Dora in the City* with my 4 yo when it struck me that all of Dora's friends were human and that there were no anthropomorphic talking animals from *Dora the Explorer*. In fact, Dora seemed amazed that someone had invented a video camera that could translate what puppies were saying.

So what happened to all of Dora's talking animal friends? Did they stay where they were when Dora moved to the city? Or were they all just imaginary and no longer exist now that Dora is a pre-teen?

Comment: You might have to ask the Map! :D

Comment: They uploaded his consciousness into the Matrix, he's MapApp now...

Comment: http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20150908006349/en/Dora-Reunites-Boots-Backpack-Rainforest-Friends-Nickelodeon%E2%80%99s

Comment: The discussion in the comments of [the other _Dora the Explorer_ question we have](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71356/19561) seems to point to it being **on topic**.

Comment: Dora had them [liquidated](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/92/9290cf9940b63f57643ae9950b03f3330770373be91d7d68eb643479f41e7a1a.jpg).

Comment: +1 for a question about Dora. Never thought I'd see her discussed on here!

Comment: I was watching and my 3 year old said that boots wouldn't go anywhere without his boots and they got stuck in quicksand and he jumped in with them

Comment: Umm - Well, let's just say they were very helpful, and delicious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out:

Season 2 Episode 2: *[Return to the Rainforest](http://dora.wikia.com/wiki/Return_to_the_Rainforest)*

> Dora's city friends travel back to the rainforest with Boots so that
>   they can rescue Backpack and Map.

Characters include: Boots, Benny Isa, Tico, Backpack, Map, Swiper, Fiesta Trio, Big Red Chicken (a personal favorite), Grumpy Old Troll, Petunia, Chocolate Tree and Mariana the Mermaid.

Season 2 Episode 7 & 8: *Rainforest Reunion* parts 1 & 2

> Dora returns to the rainforest for a picnic with Boots; Swiper gets
>   tangled in his new swiping spring; Dora is transported to a magical
>   night circus when she watches the class pet.

Comment: So would you say that they were left in the rainforest? (Make this answer bigger and post a picture!)

Comment: @TGnat - Thanks for this. Now I can tell my daughter something rather than that he wasn't real & avoid follow-on questions about Santa, Tooth Fairy and the rest of the Western mythos....